# find the power representation of $x^2 \arctan(x^3)$

Tags: calculus

Wondering what im doing wrong in this problem im ask to find the power series representation of 
$x^2 \arctan(x^3)$
now i know that arctan's power series representation is this
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}  $$

i could have sworn that for solving for this i could just have use that formula and then distribute the $x^2$ but i'm getting the wrong answer here is the steps im taking.

1- plug in $x^3$ for $x$
$$x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(x^3)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}  $$
2- distribute the $2n+1$ to $x^3$
$$x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{6n+3}}{2n+1}  $$
3- distribute the $x^2$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{6n+5}}{2n+1}  $$

however this is wrong according to my book the answer should be

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{3n+2}}{n}  $$

can someone please point out my mistake.  Please forgive me in advance for any mathematical blunders that i post. I'm truly sorry.
Thanks
Miguel

Comment: $(2n+1)(3)=6n+3$, not $6n+1$. Now add $2$.

Comment: Once you plugged in $x^3$ for $x$, you had $(x^3)^{2n+1}$ which should have given you $x^{6n + 3}$. So, you have already lost me there.

Comment: In step 2, you miscomputed $3\cdot(2n+1)$, you should have gotten $6n+3$, and in step 3, you miscomputed the exponent sum. The exponents in the final expression should be $6n+5$. What the book has is wronger, it divides by $0$, for a start.

Comment: andre and Daniel thanks for pointing out my error. @DanielFischer what do you mean by it divides by zero? sorry i just dont understand that part. Thanks for your help thus far i edited the question to contain the correct numbers.

Comment: The term of the book is $(-1)^n \frac{x^{3n+2}}{n}$. Summation starts with $n = 0$. That won't work out well. In step 3, you now have completely dropped the $x^2$, the exponent ought to be $6n+5$.

Comment: The answer should be $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k}{x}^{6\,k+5}}{2\,k
+1}}.$

Comment: thanks Daniel for explaining. so would you agree that my answer is correct?

Comment: Thank you Mhenni you pointed out that i didnt distribute correctly the x^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book's answer would be right if it said
$$
\sum_{\text{odd }n\ge 0} (-1)^{(n-1)/2)} \frac{x^{3n+2}}{n}.
$$
That would be the same as your answer, i.e.
$$
\sum_{\text{odd }n\ge 0} (-1)^{(n-1)/2)} \frac{x^{3n+2}}{n} = \sum_{n\ge0} (-1)^n\frac{x^{6n+5}}{2n+1}.
$$